# Error 500 apache server cakephp3

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, routes, cakephp-3.0

I have apache 2.2.3 server with some Cakephp2.x apps already working, but for some reason I have an error 500 on a new Cakephp3 app...

My .htaccess file look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

[image: There's a pic of the folders]

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: @aynber My error log say nothing..

Comment: Have you enabled debug mode in your config/app.php? Have you checked your server's error log (e.g. Apache), and Cake's error log (saved under your app's logs folder), and any error_log that might be in your webroot?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [CakePHP 3 Bookmark Tutorial](https://github.com/cakephp/bookmarker-tutorial).

The first `.htaccess` file in the project root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

The second `.htacess` file in the `webroot` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: My .htaccess file in the webroot directory look the same

Comment: And the first .htaccess file?

Comment: I have it like I say on the question now, but before I have it just like u say.